# Need help centering in an linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following xml layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF99E6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Was patient"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#298EB5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Hier wat extra info"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF6633"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="#298EE5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Now I want to center that datepicker in the orange container. I setted the attribute to center, but that only centers it horizontal.

I can only use linearlayout, so please no suggestions to use relative layout :)

I've been struggeling with this for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thx

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:layout_gravity` on both your `timepicker` and `orange container` and set `android:gravity="center"` to your `orange container` to make it center.

`android:gravity` define the gravity of `childs`, while `layout_gravity` define the gravity of the `layout/view` itself.

Comment: This works, quick question, can you explain why setting the gravity of the layout to center shows a different result as setting the layout_gravity of the child to center? I tought layout_gravity: center would center the child within it's parent..

Comment: AFAIK, you can only define `vertical` alignment of the `childs` through `layout_gravity` if your `LinearLayout` is `horizontal-orientated` and vice versa. That's why setting `layout_gravity` to `center` doesn't work as expected in your `vertical-orientated` `LinearLayout`(you can't define `vertical` alignment of childs).

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF6633"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**android:layout_gravity** Standard gravity constant that a child can supply to its parent.

**android:gravity**  Specifies how to place the content of an object, both on the x- 
 and y-axis, within the object itself.

So in your orange `LinearLayout` use `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: This works, quick question, can you explain why setting the gravity of the layout to center shows a different result as setting the layout_gravity of the child to center? I tought layout_gravity: center would center the child within it's parent..

Answer (score 0):

set gravity of parent linearlayout of time picker to center like following

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF6633"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```